# Can't Run on High Refresh Rate (120Hz) on Xorg

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel, mesa

I’m using an Alienware X17 R1 Laptop, with i7-11800H and GTX3070 Mobile.
The monitor panel supports 3840x2160@120Hz on Windows. Settings on Windows:

[image: Settings on Windows]

The system is Ubuntu **21.10** with 5.13.0-20 kernel. I've also tried Fedora **34** and **35 beta** with 5.14.10 kernel, and even PopOS but they gave me similar results.
**Update:** I've just updated 5.15-rc7 kernel, problem still exists.

I’ve tried both with or without NVIDIA drivers, but has got no luck.

Although there is 120Hz option, it does not do anything. The Settings Page:

[image: The Settings Page]

Now I’m not sure if it is the problem of Mesa for Intel UHD or the problem of NVIDIA driver.
However, since I can't disable dGPU or iGPU in BIOS, I'm assuming that the graphics finally outputting to the screen are handled by Intel GPU. I guess NVIDIA GPU is just a background renderer and all the data will eventually be passed to Intel GPU for output. So I highly suspect it is the problem of Intel GPU and its driver... About Page in Settings:

[image: About Page in Settings]

In `xrandr`, I can't see 120Hz available though...

> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
> eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 381mm x 214mm
> 3840x2160     60.02 +  60.01*   59.98    59.97
> 3200x1800     59.96    59.94
> 2880x1620     59.96    59.97
> ...

Can anyone help me out?

Cheers,
Stephen